# Xtext: referencing existing java packages and methods

Tags: xtext

I developed a DSL which I use together with standard java code.
In my DSL I can write things like this:

```
package:  packagename;
method: void testMethod (int, double);
```

What I want to do, is that the user of the DSL can only write package names and method signatures which already exist in the Java project.

***Example:***

When my project only consists of one package e.g. “TestPackage”, the user of the DSL should only be able to write:

```
package:  TestPackage
```

the name “TestPackage” should also be suggested by the code completor. The same shall also work with the methods.

Is it possible? And how can I do this with Xtext?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it (yet), but take a look at the relevant [Xtext documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html#contentAssist) on this.  Also, I'd look through the "[7 Languages](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/7languages.html)", find one that does what you want (which I think you'll find), and study the source.

Comment: Thanks, the ProposalProvider is exactly what I have been looking for. But I still have no idea how I can access on my java project packages, classes or methods out from the ProposalProvider.